# Debian 9 fingerprint reader at login issue

Tags: linux, debian

I'm trying to activate the fingerprint reader on my Debian 9 system. I setup my fingerprint using fprintd, and tried various configurations in a couple files from `/etc/pam.d/`. I have SDDM as my login manager and I can't make it work. Presumably, it's a bug (https://lists.debian.org/debian-qt-kde/2015/09/msg00399.html). Does anybody have a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I did found the answer:

https://www.linuxsolutions.org/faqs/generic/fingerprintauthentication

Add this content to the file /etc/pam.d/system-auth:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_fprint.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so try_first_pass likeauth nullok
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        required      pam_deny.so
```

The variation is that the command 'pam_fprint_enroll', does not exists.

Go to 'All Configurations' and then click over Users. Unlock the user and configure login with Fingerprint. That's all.

Tested in Debian 9.